# find the max/min from a list of elements

Tags: java, spring, list, algorithm, arraylist

i have a class:

```
public class item{
      TypeEnum type;
      double value;
}



 public enum TypeEnum {
    max,
    min
}
```

i have an ArrayList of items like so : {min, max, max ,max, min, min, min, max, min}

each item of the list is an object with {type(min/max), value}.

and i want to transform it to : {min, max, min, max} (with keeping the same order just replace the max, max, max ===> the biggest one instead based on the value ).

i want to replace the suit of max with only the biggest one, and suit of min with smallest one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try and do this "in-place", modifying your original list, but it will be much simpler to create a new list, adding the min or max of each sequence.

```
System.out.println(items);
        
List<Item> newItems = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0; i<items.size(); )
{
    Item pick = items.get(i);
    for(i += 1; i < items.size() && pick.type == items.get(i).type; i++)
    {
        if((pick.value > items.get(i).value) == (pick.type == TypeEnum.MIN))
            pick = items.get(i);
    }
    newItems.add(pick);
}
        
System.out.println(newItems);
```

Output:

```
[(MIN:4), (MAX:1), (MAX:5), (MAX:3), (MIN:7), (MIN:4), (MIN:1), (MAX:6), (MIN:5)]
[(MIN:4), (MAX:5), (MIN:1), (MAX:6), (MIN:5)]
```